# Как заставить переменную типа 'const char*' принимать значения переменной типа 'int'?

Tags: c++

Пишу на С++.

Надо сделать так, чтобы переменная `CharCoorNumber` принимала значения переменной `intCoorNumber`.

Заранее спасибо.

```
    int intCoorNumber = 10;

    const char* CharCoorNumber;
```

Comment: Эмм..а зачем?

Comment: @Денис Звягинцев, CharCoorNumber - это строка. ПО каким принципам хотя бы должно произойти преобразование?

Comment: CharCoorNumber - это не строка - это указатель на константу типа char, на один символ.

Comment: @Mirdin, да. Но используется, как массив символов, т.е. как строка, до первого NULL'a. Я уверен в этом. Потому что ну зачем еще. intCoorNumber не байт же ведь, чтобы ему в один символ резолвится.

Comment: @Mirdin, указатель на символ это частный случай указателя на строку, не находите?

Comment: Тогда это константная строка, менять которую указатель(CharCoorNumber), не позволит. Как решать эту проблему (и главное НАДО ЛИ) зависит от вашего проекта:

1. Сам указатель не константный, можно создать новую строку и присвоить ее адрес указателю (УТЕЧКА ПАМЯТИ)

2. Использовать const_cast для приведения к неконстантному char (НЕОПРЕДЕЛЕННОЕ ПОВЕДЕНИЕ)

3. Пересмотреть свой проект - что бы в нем таких "фокусов не было)

Comment: В Linux нет ничего проще (в 64-bit винде возможно не так, но не проверял):

     CharCoorNumber = (const char *)(long)intCoorNumber; // далее при обращении по этому указателю и intCoorNumber = 10 ловите segmehtation fault (по крайней мере в *nix)


если же хотите посмотреть на значение intCoorNumber как на массив char, то:


    CharCoorNumber = (const char *)&intCoorNumber; // теперь можете исследовать эти 4 байта по одному


и Вы успешно обошли попытки компилятора доказать Вам, что Вы собираетесь делать что-то странное.

Comment: У меня в винде нет segmentation fault. А если в UNIX сделать так:

    memcpy(&CharCoorNumber, &intCoorNumber, sizeof(char*));

Comment: @Notafe, спасибо. То что мне было нужно заработало. Я сделал так --
'    char* CharCoorNumber = itoa(intCoorNumber, CharCoorNumber,10);'.
Hо на этой строчке выводиться следующий warning--
'    'CharCoorNumber' is used uninitialized in this function'
Хотя он в этой функции инициализирован.

Comment: @Mirdin, огромное Вам спасибо. Все работает.

Comment: @Mirdin, только вот 8 для размера буфера маловато. 

Поскольку INT_MAX 2147483647, INT_MIN (-INT_MAX - 1), то  получается, что нужно брать 12.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[[@Денис Звягинцев](/users/33249/%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%81-%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B2)](/users/33249/%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%81-%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B2), нужно сделать так:

```
char* buffer = new char[8];
const char* CharCoorNumber = itoa(intCoorNumber, buffer, 10);
```

либо так:

```
char* CharCoorNumber = new char[8];
itoa(intCoorNumber, CharCoorNumber,10);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int intCoorNumber = 10;
    
    
    string temp = to_string(intCoorNumber);
    const char *CharCoorNumber = temp.c_str();
    cout << CharCoorNumber;
    
    return 0;
}
```

В данном случае, `CharCoorNumber` будет указывать на область памяти где
будет храниться наш массив char'ов.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]